# Environment variables in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I use spring and tomcat in my project. I need to get the environment variable SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL. In Apache this is done by making the corresponding settings in the php environment variable you can get $_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL"]. How to do this in TOMCAT+SPRING? Please help

Comment: You have to set apache mod_jk . This apache module provides a connector with tomcat. Some SSL variables are exported. I am not sure if SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL is available, but in any case you can export the X509Certificate to tomcat through a parameter in httpservletrequest and get the serial number. I recommend the second option because is well documented

Comment: How are you connecting httpd to Tomcat (e.g. mod_jk, mod_proxy_http, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all done!

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
......

Object o = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) o;
    X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
```

[read more](https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/)